# Feature Importance with Elastic Net?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I'm trying to see if I can do and plot the feature importance of a dataset I have using Elastic Net to figure out the feature importance. So far I have written the following code but I am unsure of what I can do to output the importance of each feature:

```
model = ElasticNet(l1_ratio=cv_model.l1_ratio_, alpha = cv_model.alpha_, max_iter=cv_model.n_iter_, fit_intercept=True, random_state=42)
model.fit(X, y)
```

And then I have followed a guide on how to output a plot showing the importance:

```
feature_importance = pd.Series(index = X.columns, data = np.abs(model.coef_))

n_selected_features = (feature_importance>0).sum()
print('{0:d} features, reduction of {1:2.2f}%'.format(
    n_selected_features,(1-n_selected_features/len(feature_importance))*100))

feature_importance.sort_values().tail(30).plot(kind = 'bar', figsize = (20,12))
```

What I fail to see is how this second line of code is related to the first one or if it has anything to do with elastic net as it does not use any of its data or variables? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm aware that there are better methods to do feature importance. This is for an exploratory statistics project where I must explain why certain methods give certain results but I am not sure if my results are correct in the first place. This is the plot that I am getting:[image: plot1]

Comment: Can you refine what you mean by "or if it has anything to do with elastic net as it does not use any of its data or variables"? The first line uses elasticnet's `model.coef_` as an estimate of feature importance, which is then used in the next two lines.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I think you just answered my question. Does model.coef_ come from the elastic net I am fitting in the first piece of code? What I don't understand is how the first piece of code is used in the second piece of code as I don't see the variables being used, but if model.coef_ is a result of the elastic net being used then thats the answer I was looking for. I just didnt know where it came from.

Comment: Those are the coefficients fit during learning. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html